# Turn kindle paperwhite into secondary display

Tags: display, external-display, kindle

Could be interesting if kindle paper white can be used as secondary display to extend the screen . There is a simple browser implemented into kindle that may help. I don't want to jailbreak my kindle and I prefer a free solution without any cost.

the main advantage is that kindle is the best way to read textual info without hurting your eyes.

Also take a look here for the same idea: http://the-digital-reader.com/2015/01/06/e-ink-demos-13-3-second-screen-e-ink-monitor-ces-2015-video/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is possible, but involves lots of work and is kind of useless.

You wouldn't call the end result a monitor, as such -- the Paperwhite logs into an SSH session, so it pretty much only works for terminals, as the lag between
wireless keyboard and the e-ink screen is around 200ms.

An article about this exploit is published by Max Ogden :
[Kindleberry Wireless: A Portable Outdoor Hackstation](http://maxogden.com/kindleberry-wireless.html).

I will not reproduce the list of required hardware, but here is what the
finished product looks like as a complete Raspberry Pi workstation :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When I first got my Kindle I wondered the same thing :) But as far as I know Amazon controls the all the code on the Kindle so it's unlikely that you could do it via USB. If you could capture your display (e.g. using VNC or something similar) and output it to a secure website you could potentially view it with the Kindle browser. However I find the experience of my Kindle's browser disappointing, especially for content that changes (as your screen output probably would).

Also according to http://cutlerish.tumblr.com/post/1272166726/kindle-browser-doesnt-support-ajax the browser doesn't support AJAX so that would make it hard to have it as a realtime display (you'd probably have to click refresh each time).

Comment: kindle display is not supposed to work good on quick changing pictures. however it is the best choice for reading text on website. I dont think ajax is also a big issue. About VNC, do you know how it can be used for this purpose? Is it free?

Comment: Fair point. Yes, there are free VNC clients. http://www.tecmint.com/vnc-desktop-access-from-web-browser/

Comment: I installed tightVNC http://www.tightvnc.com/download.php but I am somehow stuck how to set it up in windows.Do you know how?

Answer (score 0):

Extending from your idea of using it's browser, I would suggest a totally different route. We can rather create a process on server / source machine which will be able to add content to the website hosted on this machine with content tailored specifically for attached kindle device. The web page can be loaded on Kindle's browser.

Basically, nothing happens on Kindle. An optimized page with well designed navigation is created on source machine which is seen on Kindle.

This needs some work on server which is going to be easier and feasible than any other solution out there.